# tikz, how do I rotate an angle?

Tags: tikz-pgf

(EDITED TWICE) I clarified to myself my issue, pls. let me restate my post.

I wished to rotate an angle Angle(ABC) (indeed a vector) around another angle \alpha. The angle to be rotated is given either in terms of its degree \beta, or in terms of three points. The former case is indeed easy. For the latter case it seems I need package `tkz-euclide` to calculate the degree of the angle. Remaining question could be: could I do without `tkz-euclide`?

(see below for minor cosmetic issues I still have).

Any further advise you may suggest is welcome.

```
%\documentclass[convert={density=300,size=1080x800,outext=.png}]{standalone}
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}  %%KOMA class
\setkomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily\bfseries\boldmath}  %%
\usepackage{amsmath,tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{calculator}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{rulercompass}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,quotes,angles}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand\round[2][2]{\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=#1]{#2}}

\begin{document}
    \pgfmathparse{30}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\anglealpha{\pgfmathresult}

    \pgfmathparse{170}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\anglea{\pgfmathresult}

    \pgfmathparse{150}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\angleb{\pgfmathresult} 

    \pgfmathparse{135}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\anglec{\pgfmathresult} 

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    myangle/.style args= {#1/#2}{draw=black!55,<->,
        angle eccentricity=#1, angle radius=#2},
    myangle/.default = 1.05/5cm
    ]
    % grid
    \draw [color=black!5] (-3,0) grid (7,8);
    % axes
    \draw[name path=A]
    (0,0) coordinate[label=below left:{$(0,0)$}] (or) -- (0,8) node[below left] {$y$}
    (or) -- (7,0) coordinate[label=below left:$x$] (x)
    (or) -- (-3,0);
    % red line
    \path[ultra thick, draw=red]
    (0,2) coordinate (m) -- ++(\anglealpha:5) coordinate[label={[label distance=1mm]345:$ww$}] (ww);
            \draw
            let
            \p1=(0,2),\p2=(ww),  \n1={{veclen(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)}}
            in
            (\x1,\y1) -- (\n1,\y1) coordinate[label={[label distance=1mm]345:$w$}] (w) {}
            \pgfextra{\xdef\var{\n1}} ;

    % vectors C's
    \draw[name path=C0, ->] (w) to ["$\ell_0$", sloped, pos=0.8]  ++ (\anglea:7) coordinate (c0) node[left] {$C_0$};    
    \draw[name path=C1, ->] (w) to ["$\ell_1$", sloped,pos=0.85]  ++ (\angleb:6) coordinate (c1) node[left] {$C_1$};
    \draw[name path=C2, ->] (w) to ["$\ell_2$", sloped,pos=0.8]  ++ (\anglec:7) coordinate (c2) node[left] {$C_2$}; 

    % rotated vectors  
    \draw[red,dashed,->]    let \p1=($(w)-(c0)$),
                            \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
                            (ww) to ["$\ell_0$" ',text=red, pos=0.9] ++ (\anglea+\anglealpha:\n1) coordinate[label=left:$C_0^r$] (d0);

    \draw[red,dashed,->]    let \p1=($(w)-(c1)$),
                            \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
                            (ww) to ["$\ell_1$" ',text=red, pos=0.9] ++ (\angleb+\anglealpha:\n1) coordinate[label=left:$C_1^r$] (d1);

    \draw[red,dashed,->]    let \p1=($(w)-(c2)$),
                            \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
                            (ww) to ["$\ell_2$" ',text=red, pos=0.9] ++ (\anglec+\anglealpha:\n1) coordinate[label=left:$C_2^r$] (d2);

    % angles
    \draw pic[myangle, "$\alpha$"] {angle=w--m--ww} ;
    \path pic[myangle=1.5/1.5cm, "$\beta_0$" ] {angle=c0--w--m} ;
    \path pic[myangle=1.4/1.7cm, "$\beta_1$" ] {angle=c1--w--m} ;
    \path pic[myangle=1.3/1.9cm, "$\beta_2$"] {angle=c2--w--m} ;

    \path pic[myangle=1.5/1.5cm, "$\beta_0$" ] {angle=d0--ww--m} ;
    \path pic[myangle=1.4/1.7cm, "$\beta_1$" ] {angle=d1--ww--m} ;
    \path pic[myangle=1.3/1.9cm, "$\beta_2$" ] {angle=d2--ww--m} ;  
    % circles w, ww
    \draw[fill=red!5]   (ww) circle [radius=0.15] ;
    \draw[fill=red!5]   (w)  circle [radius=0.15];
    \end{tikzpicture}


    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    myangle/.style args= {#1/#2}{draw=black!55,<->, angle eccentricity=#1, angle radius=#2},
    myangle/.default = 1.05/5cm]
    % grid
    \draw [color=black!5] (-3,0) grid (7,8);
    % axes
    \draw[name path=A] (0,0) coordinate[label=below left:{$(0,0)$}] (or) -- (0,8) node[below left] {$y$}
    (or) -- (7,0) coordinate[label=below left:$x$] (x)
    (or) -- (-3,0);
    % red line
    \path[ultra thick, draw=red]
    (0,2) coordinate[label=below left:{$(0,2)$}] (m) -- ++(\anglealpha:5) coordinate[label={[label distance=1mm]345:$ww$}] (ww);
    \draw pic[myangle, "$\alpha$", <->] {angle=w--m--ww} ;
    \draw
        let
        \p1=(0,2),\p2=(ww),  \n1={{veclen(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)}}
        in
        (\x1,\y1) -- (\n1,\y1) coordinate[label={[label distance=1mm]345:$w$}] (w) {}
        \pgfextra{\xdef\var{\n1}} ;

    \draw[name path=C3, ->] (w) to ["$\ell_3$", sloped, pos=0.8] (0.25,7) coordinate (c3) node[left] {$C_3$};

        \tkzFindAngle(c3,w,m)
        \tkzGetAngle{angleOne};
        \FPround\angleOne\angleOne{0}

        \tkzMarkAngle[size=.5](c3,w,m)
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos=.82](c3,w,m){\tiny $\angleOne^\circ$}        

    % angle 0 from (ww) is line to the right, angle 90 is vertical, angle 180 is line on the left, 180+\alpha is red line, so 180+\alpha - \beta is the rotation of w--C3
    \pgfmathparse{(180+\anglealpha)-\angleOne}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\angletot{\pgfmathresult}

    \draw[red,dashed,->]    
            let \p1=(w),\p2=(c3),
            \n1 = {veclen(\x2-\x1, \y1-\y2)} in
        (ww) to ["$\ell_3$",text=red, pos=0.8] ++(\angletot:\n1) coordinate[label=left:$C_3^r$] (d0);


        \tkzFindAngle(m,ww,d0)
        \tkzGetAngle{angleTwo}
        \FPround\angleTwo\angleTwo{0}   
        \pgfmathparse{360-\angleTwo}   % return decimal part .0 . How do I delete it?
        \pgfmathsetmacro\angleTwo{\pgfmathresult}

        \tkzMarkAngle[size=.5](d0,ww,m)
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos=-.82](d0,ww,m){\tiny $\angleTwo^\circ$}              
        % circles w, ww
        \draw[fill=red!5]   (ww) circle [radius=0.15] ;
        \draw[fill=red!5]   (w)  circle [radius=0.15];

        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I still have a couple of cosmetic issues:

- how do I get  `46` instead of `46.0` from `\pgfmathparse{360-\angleTwo}`?
- indeed, why does `\tkzFindAngle(m,ww,d0)` return `314`, and `\tkzFindAngle(m,ww,d0)` resp. `-314` (instead of 46)?
- how do I write labels \betas somewhere close to the top of the arcs?

Comment: do we have MathJax  on this board?

Comment: Please post a compilable example!

Comment: No, MathJax is not active here.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

[image]

Here is the complete code:

```
\documentclass[convert={density=300,size=1080x800,outext=.png}]{standalone}
%\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}  %%KOMA class
%\setkomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily\bfseries\boldmath}  %%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calculator}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{rulercompass}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,quotes,angles}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand\round[2][2]{\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=#1]{#2}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [color=black!5] (0,0) grid (9,5); 
\draw (9,0) coordinate (a) node[right, below] {x}
-- (0,0) coordinate (b) node[left] {(0,0)} 
-- (0,5) coordinate (c) node[left] {y};
\path  (0,0) coordinate (ad)   -- (30:5cm) coordinate (dd);
\draw (ad) -- (dd) coordinate[pos=0.455](c1);
\coordinate (c2) at ($(c1)!2*2.365 cm!(dd)$); 
\draw[->,  ultra thick, red]
let
\p1=(ad),\p2=(c2),  \n1={{veclen(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)}}
in
(\x1,\y1) -- (\x2,\y2)
\pgfextra{\xdef\var{\n1}} ;

\fill[black] (\var,0) circle (2.5pt)
pic["$\alpha$", draw=black!55, thick, <<->>, angle eccentricity=1.1, angle radius=\var]{angle=a--b--dd} ;

\draw[->,   black] (0,0)coordinate(o) -- (\var ,0) coordinate (w);
\draw[->,   black] (w) -- (0 ,3.5)coordinate(ww) [fill=black] node[left] {$C$};

\draw  [fill=red!5] (w) circle [radius=0.25]  node[xshift=-0.35cm, yshift=-0.45cm] {$w$}
pic["$\beta$", draw=black,  <-, angle eccentricity=1.1, angle radius=3cm]{angle=w--o--c2};

\draw  [fill=red!5] (c2) circle [radius=0.25]  node[xshift=-0.35cm, yshift=-0.45cm] {$ww$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @ AboAmmar But \alpha and \beta are different. See my comment to  the second answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I undesrand you correctly, than you looking for something like this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

i.e., you like to draw angles between `w--b--ww` with two different radius (outer is `\alpha` and inner is `\beta`). For this I don't see necessity for any special calculation of locus radius. Also some defined coordinates are duplicated or not used (in my MWE below I remove all them):

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
myangle/.style args= {#1/#2}{draw=black!55,->,
                             angle eccentricity=#1, angle radius=#2},
myangle/.default = 1.05/5cm
                        ]
% grid
\draw [color=black!5] (0,0) grid (7,4);
% axes
\draw (0,0) coordinate[label=below left:{$(0,0)$}] (b) 
            -- (0,4) node[below left] {$y$}
      (b)   -- (7,0) node[below left] {$y$};
% red line
\path[ultra thick, draw=red]   
    (b) -- (30:5) coordinate[label={[label distance=1mm]345:$ww$}] (ww)
           ( 0:5) coordinate[label={[label distance=1mm]345:$w$ }] (w);
% arrow C
\draw[->] (w) -- (ww -| b) node[left] {$C$};
% angles
\draw pic[myangle, "$\alpha$"] {angle=w--b--ww} ;
\path pic[myangle=1.1/2.5cm, "$\beta$" ] {angle=w--b--ww} ;
% circles w, ww
\draw[fill=red!5]   (ww) circle [radius=0.25] ;
\draw[fill=red!5]   (w)  circle [radius=0.25];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
From your question edit I follows, that in the first attempt I misunderstand you (but code was very simple :-) ). Now the code in not so simple anymore ... since it is necessary to calculate vector length which is determined by intersection of `y`-axis and line `C`, correct?:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, calc, intersections, quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
myangle/.style args= {#1/#2}{draw=black!55,<->,
                             angle eccentricity=#1, angle radius=#2},
myangle/.default = 1.05/5cm
                        ]
% grid
\draw [color=black!5] (-20,0) grid (7,4);
% axes
\draw[name path=A]
    (0,0) coordinate[label=below left:{$(0,0)$}] (b)
          -- (0,4) node[below left] {$y$}
    (b)   -- (7,0) coordinate[label=below left:$x$] (x);
% red line
\path[ultra thick, draw=red]
    (b) -- (30:5) coordinate[label={[label distance=1mm]345:$ww$}] (ww)
           ( 0:5) coordinate[label={[label distance=1mm]345:$w$ }] (w);
% arrow C
\path[name path=C] (w) -- ++ (150:6);
\draw [name intersections={of=A and C, by={c}},->] 
    (w)  to ["$\ell$" ',sloped,pos=0.4]  (c) node[left] {$C$};
% arrow ?
\draw[red,dashed,->]    let \p1=($(w)-(c)$),
                            \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
                        (ww) to ["$\ell$" ',text=black] ++ (180:\n1) coordinate[label=left:?] (d);
% angles
\draw pic[myangle, "$\alpha$"] {angle=w--b--ww} ;
\path pic[myangle=1.3/1.5cm, "$\beta$" ] {angle=c--w--b} ;
\path pic[myangle=1.3/1.5cm, "$\beta$" ] {angle=d--ww--b} ;
% circles w, ww
\draw[fill=red!5]   (ww) circle [radius=0.25] ;
\draw[fill=red!5]   (w)  circle [radius=0.25];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: ![![enter image description here]

Comment: @ Zarko thanks for your help, but I think I am looking for somehing else.  Now, I wish to draw a third angle, by rotating  the angle (0,0)-w-C to an angle (0,0)-ww-?, the latter of degree \beta too. I hope I am explaining myself. Indeed, if you consider w--C as a vector, I wish to draw the same vector (lenght/direction) from ww, with slope \beta with respect to the red line.

Comment: @mario, the simplest to understand you would be, that you draw this vector by hand. in my answer I didn't rotate anything ... in which point start third vector? if you add to my MWE line`\draw[red, dashed] (b)-- (60:5);`, does it lie as you wish?

Comment: @ Zarko  I edited code and picture. Hope I clarify issue. Thks for you help.

Comment: @mario, see addendum to my answer. is now ok?